# Do clouds charge upon the storage usage or processing power or both?

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, process, aws-cost-explorer

I am interested to know if I want to deploy my Kubernetes cluster on a cloud service like AWS, do they charge upon the storage my application uses or the processing power it uses or both?

Is there any simple formula to get an idea about how do they charge?

For example which one is better, using more storage but less processing power or vice versa?

Comment: What about going to the clouds and reading their payment basics? It is not like i.e. Microsoft does not have even calculators for every service on their website. AWS must have something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS charges you for CPU / processing, memory, storage, and bandwidth. It depends on the service though. You can use Elastic Kubernetes service, EC2 and install K8S, run ECS, etc. You can use "serverless" fargate containers where you don't manage the instance, or EC2 instances.

To estimate your costs try the AWS [price calculator](https://calculator.aws/).

Comment: There is no rule of thumb to say using more CPU or memory is more beneficial compare to using more storage for example?

Comment: You should benchmark your workload.